# Calculus of residues

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I try to calculate the following residue

```
Clear[α];
f[z_]:=π^2 Cot[(π z α)^(1/2)];
g[z_]:=f[z+(-π/2 + 2 k π)^2/(π α)];
res[k_]=Residue[FullSimplify[TrigToExp@g[z],k\[Element]Integers],{z,0}]
```

but it does not work.  Is it possible calculate the residue automatically?

To clarify: if you try to calculate

```
f[z_]:= π^2 Tan[(π z α)^(1/2)];
Assuming[k\[Element]Integers,Residue[f[z],{z,(π/2+k π)^2/(π α)}]]
```

you get $0$, but if you calculate

```
f[z_]:= π^2 Tan[(π z α)^(1/2)];
Assuming[k\[Element]Integers,Residue[f[z],{z,(π/2+1 π)^2/(π α)}]]
```

you get `-((3 π^2)/α)`

Comment: Once I corrected your syntax by inserting several semicolons to separate lines and ran the code I got $0$...  Might this be the correct answer?

Comment: No if you subtitute 1 in k no gives answer

Comment: I get `res[1] = 0`.  Please fix your syntax and re-run your code.  And why is your title Residue4?

Comment: David Please look the question

Comment: And what is wrong with those answers?  What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I try to automatize the residue Calculus for  a  k integers

Comment: `cot` is not `tan` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to avoid dealing with the singularity by considering the inverse:

```
f[z_] := π^2 Tan[(π z α)^(1/2)];

inv = Simplify[
    Series[1/f[z], {z, (π/2+k π)^2/(π α), 1}],
    Assumptions->k ∈ Integers && k>0
];
inv //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{\alpha  \left(z-\frac{\pi  (2 k+1)^2}{4 \alpha }\right)}{\pi ^2 (2 k+1)}+O\left(\left(z-\frac{\pi  (2 k+1)^2}{4 \alpha
>    }\right)^2\right)$

Now we can find the residue of the inverse of the inverse:

```
res[k_] = Residue[1/inv, {z, (π/2+k π)^2/(π α)}];
res[k]
```

> -(((1 + 2 k) π^2)/α)

Let's compare:

```
res /@ Range[5]
Residue[f[z], {z, (π/2+# π)^2/(π α)}]& /@ Range[5]
```

> {-((3 π^2)/α), -((5 π^2)/α), -((
>     7 π^2)/α), -((9 π^2)/α), -((11 π^2)/α)}
>
> {-((3 π^2)/α), -((5 π^2)/α), -((
>     7 π^2)/α), -((9 π^2)/α), -((11 π^2)/α)}

Comment: Thanks Carl Woll again

Answer (score 2):

The same solution using `Table`and `FindSequenceFunction`:

```
f[z_] := π^2*Tan[(π z α)^(1/2)]
sol = Table[Residue[f[z], {z, ((π/2) + k π)^2/(π α)}], {k, 1, 5}]
Res = FindSequenceFunction[sol, k] // Simplify
```

> $\left\{-\frac{3 \pi ^2}{\alpha },-\frac{5 \pi ^2}{\alpha },-\frac{7 \pi ^2}{\alpha },-\frac{9 \pi ^2}{\alpha },-\frac{11 \pi ^2}{\alpha }\right\}$
>
> $-\frac{\pi ^2 (2 k+1)}{\alpha }$